# invalid literal for int() with base 10 with a file that only contains integers

Tags: python, file, compiler-errors, int, literals

```py
rows = []
FILE = open("testing.txt", "r")
for blob in FILE: rows.append([int(i) for i in blob.split(" ")])
```

Here testing.txt contains

```
01 23 04   05 67
08 09 10
11
12
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2086c8bf9ab4> in <module>()
      1 rows = []
      2 FILE = open("testing.txt", "r")
----> 3 for blob in FILE: rows.append([int(i) for i in blob.split(" ")])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So my question is: what's wrong with int()? I thought it's perfectly ok if the argument is an integer (so `int(5) == 5` for example). Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you use list(f) or f.readlines() to get to the lines in the file?

Comment: Peter Varo: Yeah it works when I get rid of `\n` and make sure there's only one blank space in between each consecutive numbers. But why was the author in this link <http://code.jasonbhill.com/python/project-euler-problem-67/> able to succeed when the triangle.txt contains 100 rows?

Comment: triange.txt <http://projecteuler.net/project/triangle.txt> and <http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=67>

Comment: I don't have any problem using his code on the given triangle.txt, possibly if you opened it in an editor, the editor may have added additional markup.

Comment: Radio: yeah the code with triangle.txt works for me too, but I don't understand why testing.txt keeps getting the invalid literal error even if I close the editor...

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as noted, is the newlines.

I suggest using `split()` instead of `split(" ")`.  This will treat all whitespace as a separator, including newlines.  Thus you will avoid the call of `int()` on `\n`.

Comment: A. E. Drew: I think the intention is to append a new entry to "rows" once it gets to the next line. So for instance, if the file contains: 1\n 2 3, I'm expecting `rows == [[1],[2,3]]`

Comment: @YifengXu, I think you will get the behavior you want with `split()`.  Each row is still appended separately in your for loop.  You just avoid running `int()` on `'\n'` in your list comprehension. The only difference is an empty line will append an empty list to rows rather than causing an error.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks! I'm still curious how the author in the link <http://code.jasonbhill.com/python/project-euler-problem-67/> got away using `split(" ")` with triangle.txt. Any guess/idea?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your testing.txt have newline code in the end. Add `if` in list comprehension:

```
for blob in FILE:
    rows.append([int(i) for i in blob.split(" ") if i.isdigit()])
```

Comment: This was my first guess, but I deleted it.. damned:)

Comment: @YifengXu if needed for check the value from iterator (list from split). More here - http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: But `if i` will not filter out `\n` because `\n` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

You can put everything into a readable one-liner:

```
with open('testing.txt') as fobj:
    rows = [[int(item) for item in row.split()] for row in fobj if row.strip()]
```

The `with`will guarantee that the file will be closed after you leave the context, i.e. after you dedent. BTW, `split()`without arguments is especially
designed to split lines found in a file because it splits at all whitespace characters: `' \t\r\n\v\f'`. To avoid an empty list for an empty line check that `row.strip()`is true.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I would write your code like so:

```
with open('testing.txt','r') as f:
    data=[[int(n) for n in line.strip().split()] for line in f]
```